# discord.py's on_member_leave event isn't working

Tags: python, discord.py

Making a bot that logs basic events, like `on_member_join` and `on_message` has been working, but when I implemented the `on_member_leave`, that event hasn't been working. I have previously turned on intents. I've tried adding,

```
print ('User Has Left')
```

It still hasn't been working, what am I doing wrong, what are some things I need to know. Here is the script..

```
@guild.bot.event
async def on_member_leave(member):
      print ('%s has left' % (member.name))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on_member_leave` doesn't exist, `on_member_remove` is correct. I confused it with `on_guild_leave`